# Rotating an itextsharp PdfPtable

Tags: c#, itext

Hy,
I want to know if it's possible to rotate a PdfPTable. I have a template pdf where I need to add a table under a specific element but I can't find a way to achieve this.
I tried adding the table to a paragraph but I'm not able to rotate the paragraph. this is my code

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(15);
foreach(var row in Rows)
{
    PdfPCell[] cells = new PdfPCell[] { 
                    new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row.ID.ToString())) 
    //***MANY OTHER CELLS***//
    };
    PdfPRow row = new PdfPRow(cells);
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
table.CompleteRow();
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Add(table);

PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0,-1f,1f,0,0,reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width);
doc.Add(paragraph);
```

I want to add the table under my template, I could even add the table to the template if this could be helpful.
someone has some ideas? thank's

Comment: Are you sure you want to import the page into a `PdfWriter` instance? Wouldn't it be much easier for you to use `PdfStamper` instead to add the table to the existing page? Please clarify, as this has a significant impact on any possible answer.

Comment: thank's!! your answer helped me, I've started using PdfStamper and everything it's ok now!!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, so that the 0 answers mark is gone ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `PdfWriter` which involves rotating the page and rotating the table you're adding on top of that page. You can avoid this problem, by adding the table using `PdfStamper`. In this case, you can just add the table and if the rotation setting of the page is OK, the table will automatically be rotated too, unless you use the following line:

```
stamper.setRotateContents(false);
```

By default, the extra content will have the same rotation of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Please see below to rotate your table:

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 20, 20, 42, 35);
```

To rotate cell is

```
pdfPCell.Rotation = 90;
```

Hope above will help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't achieve result in C# to rotate content in table by 180 degrees with

```
pdfPCell.Rotation = 180;
```

but got with

```
table.DefaultCell.Rotation = 180;
```